# Finding the concentration from a dilution

Tags: solutions, concentration

This must be a very basic question but I have gotten confused over it.
How would I find the concentration of each component of the reaction for each experiment from this data? I am guessing it can’t be the concentrations given, is that for some stock solution?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solving one out of the four would be good enough to understand the concept behind this. Therefore, I shall explain the first experiment and the concentrations of the components in the solution produced.

In experiment 1 all four are added in equal quantities. Finding the total volume, we get the total volume

$$V_\text{tot} = \pu{4 ml}.$$

Assuming the amount of $i$th solute to be denoted by $n_i,$ its molarity $c_i$ can be found as

$$c_i = \frac{n_i}{V_\mathrm{tot}}.$$

Now, we add $\pu{1 ml}$ of $\pu{2.0 M}$ acetone. This is equivalent to saying we add $1/1000$ of $\pu{2 mol}$ of acetone. Therefore we add $\pu{2 mmol}$ (millimoles) of acetone.

This means that we have $\pu{2 mmol}$ of acetone in $\pu{4 mL}$ of water. Using the formula for molarity we get that acetone is in $\pu{0.5 M}$ in solution.

Hope you can follow on for the other parts as well, the concept remains the same.